# How to create a multiple columns with HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm a beginner in programming using CSS and I want to create columns like this ! can you show me the css and html?
http://i.cubeupload.com/WX5lzW.png

Comment: You could 'view-source' on the page you're viewing.  Can you provide an example you've tried so we can help you with specific CSS and/or HTML issues you're having?

Comment: This is what i want to create http://i.cubeupload.com/WX5lzW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use three divs like so:

```
<div style="display: block; float:left; background-color: green; width: 33.3%; height: 100px;">
</div>
<div style="display: block; float:left; background-color: blue; width: 33.3%; height: 100px;">
</div>
<div style="display: block; float:left; background-color: red; width: 33.3%; height: 100px;">
</div>
```

Add margin to the divs to give some spacing around them.

Comment: you can do that put the image & text in the divs, add some margin. I just put background color on to show the different divs. I would suggest maybe looking into a css framework like bootstrap, you can just add classes to divs and it'll work out the margins for you.

Comment: Thanks , how can i add a image using css

Comment: Use the html image tag within the divs like so: <div><img src="path/to/image.png"></div> I would suggest looking at sites like w3schools.com to learn the basics.

Comment: Already did but i want to combine it into the css not using the html